# How to replace the periods values in a dataframe to null or other values?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, replace

The following code:

```
print(PB_PID_group)
print(type(PB_PID_group))
```

**gives me:**

```
PI
.             [., 5398, 5482, 5467]
1311    [5185, ., 5398, 5467, 5576]
1667                      [., 6446]
3352                            [.]
935                             [.]
Name: PID, dtype: object
<class 'pandas.core.series.Series'>
```

I then changed this to dataframe (pandas)

```
PB_PID_df = pd.DataFrame(PB_PID_group)

print(type(PB_PID_df))
```

which gives me:

`<class 'pandas.core.frame.DataFrame'>`

Then I write the dataframe to a file:

```
pd.DataFrame.to_csv(PB_PID_df,'updated_df_table.txt', sep='\t', index=True, na_rep='none')
```

writes:

```
PI      PID
.       ['.' '5398' '5482' '5467']
1311    ['5185' '.' '5398' '5467' '5576']
1667    ['.' '6446']
3352    ['.']
935     ['.']
```

I want to remove the lines that has `PI` values as period (.) and only remove period from `PID` column.

I tried.

```
PB_PID_df['PID'] = PB_PID_df['PID'].replace(to_replace='.', value='na', regex=True)
```

I also tried without `regex` and other method options, but its not working.

Any suggestions.

Thanks,

Comment: try `df.drop('.', inplace=True)` to see if it gets rid of that row

Comment: Thanks, that worked. How to get rid of the `'.'` in PID columns?

Comment: because your data type is list you need to update those list values I think `df['PID'].apply(lambda x: [x if x != '.' else 'na' for x in x])` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you made a DataFrame from the existing Series, the index was resused, so to drop the initial row you needed to call `drop` and pass the label for that row `'.'`.

As you now have lists as the dtype which is weird, you can't use `replace` anymore as this looks for exact values to find and won't understand list types so you can use `apply` to iteratively test each value and replace with string `'na'`:

```
In [12]:
# setup some data
df = pd.DataFrame({'PID':[['.',5398, 5482, 5467], [5185, '.', 5398, 5467, 5576]]}, index=['.',1311])
df

Out[12]:
                              PID
.           [., 5398, 5482, 5467]
1311  [5185, ., 5398, 5467, 5576]
```

Now `drop` and replace using `apply` with `lambda` and list comprehension:

```
In [13]:
df.drop('.',inplace=True)
df['PID'] = df['PID'].apply(lambda x: [x if x != '.' else 'na' for x in x])
df

Out[13]:
                               PID
1311  [5185, na, 5398, 5467, 5576]
```

**EDIT**

To answer the additional query in comments, to remove a value modify the list comprehension so that the `if` condition is at the end:

```
In [19]:
df['PID'] = df['PID'].apply(lambda x: [x for x in x if x != '.'])
df

Out[19]:
                           PID
1311  [5185, 5398, 5467, 5576]
```

Comment: What if I want: `1311  [5185, 5398, 5467, 5576]`

Comment: although it may seem useful to store lists, it's a bit counter-productive as you lose the vectorised methods available if the dtypes were simple numerical or string types. The only thing you gain is some nicer syntax for reading, writing to csv files and column/index lookup but value lookup won't play nice and will be a pain, just a suggestion

Comment: `df['PID'] = df['PID'].apply(lambda x: [x for x in x if x != '.'])` basically move the `if` condition to the end